# Como solucionar "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Usuario' not found"

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Criei esta classe (começando agora com POO) no arquivo `Funcionarios.php`, lá ela funciona:

```
class Funcionario{
    public $departamento;
    public $salario;
    public $dataEntrada;
    public $cpf;

    public function recebeAumento(){
        $this->salario += $this->salario*0.1;
    }

    public function calculaGanhoAnual(){
        return "$".$this->salario*13 .".00";
    }

    function __construct($departamento, $salario, $dataEntrada, $cpf){
    # para fazer qualquer acao com o funcionaro e necessario que o seu
    # cadastro esteja completo, entao faz sentido colocar isso num construct
        $this->departamento = $departamento;
        $this->salario = $salario;
        $this->dataEntrada = $dataEntrada;
        $this->cpf = $cpf;
    }
}
```

e tentei usa-la no `teste_funcionario.php`:

```
<?php
require "../model/Funcionario.php";

# para se criar um funcionario e necessario passar em ordem as 
seguintes informacoes:
# departamento, salario, data de entrada e cpf

$funcionarioPiloto = new Usuario("caixa",1500,"15/02/2018", 
"000.000.008-00");

$funcionarioPilotoDois = new 
Usuario("estoque",1400,"14/07/2018","000.000.009-00");
```

E toda vez ela dá esse erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Usuario' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/trabalhinho123programacaodoseujaguara/controller/teste_funcionario.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/trabalhinho123programacaodoseujaguara/controller/teste_funcionario.php on line 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O nome da sua classe é `Funcionario`, sendo assim, você tem que instanciar a classe `Funcionario` e não a classe `Usuario` (que nem existe).

O correto seria:

```
$funcionarioPiloto = new Funcionario("caixa", 1500, "15/02/2018", "000.000.008-00");

$funcionarioPilotoDois = new Funcionario("estoque", 1400, "14/07/2018", "000.000.009-00");
```